# Facebook Api only returns 25 events max?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

I am testing my new iframe app,

trying to get all events of an user, using the graph api.

```
$tempevent = $facebook->api('/me/events', 'get', array("fields"=>"id, name, start_time"));
```

so it only returns 25 events .. the farthest events.

Any ideas?

Just checked out the JS-Version.. same result.

```
FB.api('/me/events', function(response) {
    console.log("event id: " + response.data[0].id); //k
    console.log("event id: " + response.data[24].id);  //k 
    console.log("event id: " + response.data[25].id); //not k 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use FQL:

```
$tempevent = $this->facebook->api(array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => 'SELECT eid, name, start_time FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me())'
));
```

Explanation:
Here you are getting all the events from the [`event`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event/) table where the *event id* (`eid`) is `IN` the [`event_member`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event_member/) table where the user `me()` is linked to, whether he is `attending`, `unsure`, `declined`, or `not_replied`.

Comment: @Sven Koluem: Updated my answer with explanation and references.

Comment: thx perfect explanation. do you have also an idea how i can get all events generated by my app / or all user of my app .. to get their events?

Comment: @Sven Koluem: events created *through* your application is on behalf of a user..now "*how to get all users of my app?*" seems to be a challenging question!

Comment: yes, that's the best way of getting all the events at once ;)

Comment: @ifaour what do yo mean .. "is on behalf on user", i would like to give the user an overview about all events of the other users.
but indeed it seems to be quite difficult.

Comment: @Sven Koluem: I meant, the owner of the event will be the USER that authorized your app and not the application itself. And yes that would be very difficult to achieve based on my answer on your other question!

Comment: no that's not correct at all. there are two subjects, if i click on the event.. my name / application name. so it is stored.. but not accessable with the api :(

Comment: @Sven Koluem: `event_members` is showing the user id, also in the `event` table explains the `creator` as `The user ID of the creator of the event being queried.` now true in the event page you'll see the application name present as creator..but I suppose it should be `via app_name`

Comment: is there a possibilty on stackoverflow to write pms?

Comment: yes, there's chat rooms in SO, for [facebook](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211/facebook), also you can contact me on my email

Answer (score 2):

I recomment you try to access the following URL `https://graph.facebook.com/me/events?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN`. Scroll down. You will see that facebook returns paginated results. Beside the `data` param (which is returned by the sdk) you have another `paging` param. This one contains links to more results, called `next` and `previous`. Use them to retrieve more events.

Also, if you want to retrieve more events per page you can add the `limit` param among access_token. For example: `https://graph.facebook.com/me/events?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN&limit=50`.

Good luck.

Comment: don't get it at all.. how to do this in php?
$facebook->api('/me/events', 'get', array("fields"=>"id, name, start_time",'access_token' => $facebook->getAccessToken(), 'limit' => 50));  ??

Comment: you do it by fetching directly that url, like `json_decode(file_get_contents(url))`. but use what ifaour suggested, i just showed you that facebook gives you all the events, but paginated, when using graph api